# Ubuntu phone problem!

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I tried to install ubuntu phone on my galaxy nexus, but during the process the pc crashed. When i tried to boot up the phone again it shows the google-sign, and then it turns black :( I have tried to go to recovery mode, and followed the steps on how to install ubuntu phone manually, but i don't have an sd-card. Is it possible to use the abd sidelode? i have tried to write:

```
adb sideload <ubuntu.zip>
```

but I only get the message:

```
bash: ubuntu.zip (filename): No such a file or directory
```

What am I supposed to do now? Is my phone totaly "dead"?

Please help! I know I am doing this at my own risk...

Comment: I am also getting the message:

bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: To clarify, **sdcard** is internal storage in Android land.

Answer (score 2):

If you damaged the state of the Android device during an attempt to install, then you first need to recover to a known state.

**Re-install the Galaxy Nexus firmware, taking care to install the correct one. (there are several to choose from.)**

[developers.google.com < Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#takju)